# UIPageViewController to present similar to a popover within main View

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

In my application, I want to create a *user-story (onboarding guide)* which would be a 3-4 stack of swipe-able cards. User can swipe through and after the last one is swiped, application starts. User can also skip anytime s/he likes.

Below is similar to what I would like to have.

**Expected Result:**

[image]

You have the Main View appearing a bit on the sides.

I started using `UIPageViewController` to manage such on-boarding stack of cards, which I did successfully. (I have 3 separate views - which feed into my custom `UIPageViewController`). I also added that small swipe dots (what you see generally at the bottom of such onboarding stack). However, since ultimately I wanted my Main View behind this Page View, I started off using Container View as suggested in this [tutorial](http://samwize.com/2015/10/13/how-to-create-uipageviewcontroller-in-storyboard-in-container-view/). I pulled in a containerView inside my Main View, made it's controller's class my custom PageViewController class.

Though I was able to mimic what I wanted, as you see below, most of the customisations which I did in my custom `UIPageViewController` are not available to use in this Container View's controller (which now is my Custom PageViewController).

**Actual Result:**

[image]

Customisations which I did in my Custom UIPageViewController were:
1. Swipe (or Navigation) dots at the bottom.
2. Color of these dots.
3. Background color
4. I am planning to do more, such as changing the bounds of it to RoundedRect, etc.

On exploring in Attributes inspector, here is what attributes are available for changing in any UIPageViewController:

**Attributes for a UIPageViewController, in general**

[image]

And below are the attributes which appear for Container controller, which now should actually be a subclass of `UIPageViewController`, isn't it? As you see there is no section for "Page View Controller" at all.

**Attributes for my Custom UIPageViewController (Container's VC is not a subclass of that)**

[image]

So, I was looking for two things:

**Questions:**

1. Is this the best way to achieve what I want? (I was also thinking of using UIAlert, etc. to achieve this but decided against it, as I wanted more control).
2. What is the issue with Container's controller that on changing it to a UIPageViewController, all settings go to default.

My priority is to get a better idea on my first question. Pointers would for sure be helpful. Many thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve your goal using a page view controller – it would involve creating a view controller for the tutorial card with a clear, translucent (not opaque) background.

You want the page view controller to fill the entire screen so the paging effect won't be cropped to the bounds of the tutorial card. The paging along with direction locking the scrolling will allow you to effectively dismiss your cards until there are no more to present.

So rather than using a container view, present your page view controller with the back stripped out, and the presentation set to 'Over Current Context' – this leaves the view controller behind visible. The page view controller will present an array of tutorial card view controllers that you configure.

The tutorial card view controller will also have no background, but in the center of the view will be a floating card containing your text and dismiss button. Connect the outlets from the storyboard to your custom tutorial card view controller so you can configure multiple instances with different text.

After this make sure you give the view controller a storyboard identifier so it can be instantiated when configuring the page view controller data source. Create your array of tutorial card view controllers and set up the data source to present them.

I wouldn't say that this is the best way of doing as there are many 'swipeable card' packages out there that give this functionality and more, but for the sake of DIY it is a feasible route.

Comment: Thanks Callam. This actually works and along with changing run time attributes, I actually am able to mimic what I expected in the first place. The issue is: My main VC should always be in the background. And the PageView along with 2/3 views should be on the top. I did change the opacity of my three views underlying the PageViewController. It looks good. Still I can't see my main VC, because since I want these cards to appear I have set the PageViewController as Intial View Controller. How can I set the main VC as initial ViewController and add my PageViewController's views on its top?

Comment: If you were to make your main VC the initial controller, in the `viewDidAppear`, present the page view controller modally over the current context. This can be done via the segue interface builder or programmatically by setting the modal presentation type of the controller you're presenting to `.overCurrentContext`.

Comment: Will try that and see if it works. However, I have received the bulk of the answer which I need from your answer. After I give it a try, I will accept this as answer. Plus, understandably swipeable card packages are aplenty and can be used.

Comment: In the below answer, "yellow" coloured one is my main VC. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I was able to do it, as per my need. Adding in detail, in case other people might benefit. 
My main ViewController is my entry point. Within the main VC, I used a Container VC. I dragged in a UIPageViewController and create three VCs which would be the pages within my UIPageViewController. I removed the ContainerView's default controller which comes with it. And actually embedded (Embed Segue) the UIPageViewController into the ContainerView (which in within the main VC).
The whole arrangement looks like:

[image]

This way my mainVC can remain the initial VC. I can make my three views smaller with a corner radius, which looks like a popover arrangement, as is what I needed. I did not use the default UIPageControl which is used by UIPageViewController. Instead, I dragged in a UIPageViewControl onto my main VC (not the container VC within). This way, I was able able to add whatever buttons (such as "Skip") which probably is not possible when using default UIPageControl. Meaning thereby, I did not use these in my UIPageViewController code.

```
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {}

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {}
```

In order to control the new UIPageControl which I had dragged in, I introduced delegation protocol within my UIPageViewController and made my main VC follow the protocol. Then, I could basically send message to my main VC (UIPageControl is an outlet in the main VC) when the user was swiping the pages.

```
protocol OnboardingViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func onboardingPageViewController(onboardingPageViewController: OnboardingViewController, didUpdatePageCount count: Int)
    func onboardingPageViewController(onboardingPageViewController: OnboardingViewController, didUpdatePageIndex index: Int)
}
```

At the end of it, the result is the following which is exactly what I want. In case anyone wants to look over the code, it's on [github](https://github.com/apraka16/swipeableOnboardingUIPageView).

[image]

**EDIT:** Added shadow behind the Views, hence changed the gif.